# Connecting iPhone to an ODBC Database

Tags: odbc, ios

I'm new to iOS development. I have to make an application that connects to a Sybase database. My bet would be to use ODBC. Does anyone know how to connect to an ODBC enabled database from within objective C.

I've encountered applications that can do this but I don't seem to find any specific iOS related documentation or source code examples. Does anyone have even the slightest idea?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

There is a new ODBC SDK for iOS available at http://ODBCrouter.com/ipad complete with screenshots and an app you may download and use with the online demonstration system.

Comment: This is very old, and the web site is archaic and has no indication it is kept up.  The contact form didn't work as well.  Does anyone know, does this still work?  Is it code or a library that I can include in my iOS app?  Does it support x64 bit frameworks, and iOS 8?

Answer (score 1):

Mostly you want to get to remote databases through a web service layer. The app I'm currently working on does a TON of database interaction, and I wrote a number of PHP scripts that live on a web server on the same machine with the database. My PHP receives web requests from the app, does the DB work, and responds with JSON objects. You can obviously use any web layer you want--asp, perl, you name it--and respond with XML if you prefer. Doesn't matter.

I don't know of anybody actually interacting live with a database interface, ODBC or otherwise, directly from the phone. The way people seem to be going about it is via an intermediate web app layer.

Answer (score 0):

iPhone SDK can use SQLite I am unsure of others. Perhaps the best choice will to be to free it of the ODBC issue and write a web service façade to provide the database access.

Comment: That's one possibility. My boss wants more options though :P

I know via iODBC.org, you can access ODBC databases from the Mac OSX platform. They provide a framework for that. Does anyone if this framework could work with iOS/iPhone?

Comment: iODBC (http://iodbc.org/) has not been ported to iOS yet -- but this port planned for an indefinite future.  Demand can obviously help accelerate that... (ObDisclaimer - I work for OpenLink Software (http://openlinksw.com/), which maintains and supports the iODBC project.  We do offer other solutions which could deliver similar end results, depending on the deployment and application.)

Answer (score 0):

WCF Data Services /w Entity Framework and the OData client library for iOS will give you full CRUD access to the schema.